# show same form in multiple template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a form which needs to be shown in two different template. One is the main page i.e on the invitation page to show just the invitation form and another in the homepage. When a form is filled from the homepage, if there is error, the error should be shown from the main page of that form i.e invitation template.

I could show the form in invitation template and error display is working perfectly either but if i fill the form from the homepage, i always get '**this field is required'** error even if i pass the right value.

Here is my code

```
def requestInvitation(request):
    form = InviteForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        join = form.save(commit=False)
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        already_join, created = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
        if created:
            already_join.invite_code = get_invite_code()
            already_join.save()
            send_request_received_email.delay(email,already_join.email_tracker)
            messages.success(request, "Thank you for your interest.")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'invitation/invitation.html', context)


def index(request):
    form = InviteForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {"form": form}
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, "home.html", context)
    else:
        return render(request, "home.html", context)


url(r'^request/$', requestInvitation, name='request-invitation'),
```

**UPDATE**

```
def index(request):
    form = InviteForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        join = form.save(commit=False)
        print ('noin', join)
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        already_join, created = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
        print ('already_join', already_join, created)
        if created:
            already_join.invite_code = get_invite_code()
            already_join.save()
            send_request_received_email.delay(email,already_join.email_tracker)
            messages.success(request, "Thank you for your interest")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/invitations/request')
    # return HttpResponseRedirect('/invitations/request')
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

I changed my index view to this. If i fill the right value, the data gets saved but if there is error it does not redirect to /invitation/request page to show that error. If i use the HttpResponseRedirect at the else condition of form.is_invalid() then when i enter the homepage, i am instantly redirected to /invitation/request page.

Comment: You are redirected because: 1. **form.is_valid()** is False since it is rendered for the first time, 2. **if created** is False, so end up in the else statement which is redirecting you to /invitiations/request/.

Comment: What i have to do then please?

Answer (score 0):

You are not validating and saving the form in your home view, so basically it remains empty

Comment: Does that mean i have to place the same code(requestInvitation view) in home view too?

Comment: Yes, the code within **form.is_valid()** should be repeated for the home view (or slightly adjusted depending on what you want to achieve). At least you need to check is the form is valid, and then save when it is valid. If it's not, just rerender with errors.

Comment: In the form action attribute, i should pass the url of /index, right?

Comment: That is correct, but if you are going to post to the current url the action attribute can be omitted

Comment: But if there is an error i want to show the error in invitation template form not in the homepage because actual page of that form is invitation template.

Comment: That is no problem. You could redirect to the invitation view if the form is invalid. If it is valid you just save and rerender the home page view.

Comment: I have updated my issue with invalid form check. I am redirected to /invitation/request page when i load the homepage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141504/discussion-between-dentemm-and-milan).